# Excel Form: Objects deformed when published in PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, textbox, dropdown

I have a form developed with a Excel which I use objects - such Form Controls and ActiveX Form - to receive input data and to show the the results obtained. As routine, after generating all results I'm saving as PDF to store the document (or spreadsheet) so all information must be clearly visible.

When I executed such routine, my PDF form is generated with deformed/different formatting objects. For example: results of textbox are visible, but his borders don't. The possible way to have a corresponding view - judging by the view in the worksheet - is to increasing the zoom.

There's any other way ou any configuration method to correct that?

Comment: Strictly speaking, what you are describing is not a deformation. If the object looks OK when you zoom into the PDF, then what you are seeing is a limitation of Acrobat to render lines or other details on your screen. The solution is to either live with it or increase the width of the lines

Comment: How are you saving the image?  Depending if you're using bitmap versus png versus jpeg, etc., will make a difference.